# How to click to show various elements without duplicate the function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I know how to make a toggle:

```
<div onclick="text1()">Hello</div>
<div id="click1">World</div>

<script>
function text1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("click1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

However, if I have several texts to click like that, how to keep it short by not duplicate the script? That is, if I have:

```
<div onclick="text1()">Hello</div>
<div id="click1">World</div>

<div onclick="text2()">Hi</div>
<div id="click2">Earth</div>

...

<div onclick="textn()">I see you</div>
<div id="clickn">Universe</div>
```

then what can I do to not duplicate n functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a value in the function call to indicate which id you want the function to refer to:

```js
function text(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="text('click1')"><b>Hello</b></div>
<div id="click1">World</div>

<div onclick="text('click2')"><b>Hi</b></div>
<div id="click2">Earth</div>
```

Still manual, but adds minimal complexity, and no need to duplicate the function.

Answer (score 2):

let your function=`text()` accept one parameter named `id`. Then in the HTML, pass the ID of one Dom element you'd like to toggle.

Even you can create another function (ex: textAll), it accepts one parameter of css selector. Then uses `document.querySelectorAll` and `for-loop` to toggle all elements match the selector.

**Like below demo**:

```js
function text(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function textAll(selectorPath) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(selectorPath);
  [...items].forEach(x => {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div onclick="text('id1')">Hello</div>
<div id="id1">World</div>
<br>
<div onclick="text('id2')">A</div>
<div id="id2">A1</div>
<br>
<div onclick="textAll('#id4')">C</div>
<div id="id4">C1</div>
<br>
<div onclick="textAll('div[id]')">All with ID</div>
<div id="id5">All with ID</div>
<br>
<div onclick="textAll('div')">All</div>
<div id="id6">All</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<div onclick="text(this.getAttribute('value'))" value="1">Hello</div>
<div id="click1">World</div>

<div onclick="text(this.getAttribute('value'))" value="2">Hello</div>
<div id="click2">World</div>

<script>
function text(n) { // take a the value as a parameter
  var x = document.getElementById(`click${n}`); // get id in format 'click1'
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

This will shorten the code, but will mean you have to add a

```
value="n"
```

tag into every clickable div

Answer (score 1):

**you need to use class selector and dom traversing for standard coding**

i think it's smart solution ..

you can try this

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               
                if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('display')) {
                   

                    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('display');
                } 
                else  {
                    
                   e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('display');
                }

            })
        });
```

```css
.display{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<button class="button">Click</button>
<div class="text">World</div>

<br>

<button class="button">Click</button>
<div class="text">World</div>


<br>

<button class="button">Click</button>
<div class="text">World</div>

<br>
```

Comment: I embed this code to my WordPress site but it doesn't work. Do you know why? Obviously I put the js code in `<script>` tag

Comment: it just doesn't hide the text initially, and clicking the buttons don't do anything. There is no error

Comment: do you write exact my code in your site  ? or are  you change something ?

Comment: @Ooker add `class="text display".. `  `display ` class to hide the text initially..

Answer (score 1):

How about jQuery instead much fewer lines?

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/d9q8rcag/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clicker').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.click').toggle();
    });
});
```

Does that help?